# Problem with object layouts and custom global actions in package (2GP)

Tags: page-layout, namespace, global-actions, 2gp, packaging

So I'm trying to install a new 2GP package that has an object with a custom global action as part of it's page layout. I'm running into problems and I'm wondering whether I've missed something or if this issue needs raising with SF.

So when I'm installing my managed package into a non-namespaced org I get the following error:

```
1) (Portfolio__c-Model Portfolio Layout) In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named testsfns__Duplicate_Portfolio found, Details: Portfolio__c-Model Portfolio Layout: In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named testsfns__Duplicate_Portfolio found
```

If I install the package into a namespaced scratch org(testsfns) it works fine.

And if I rebuild the package with the Portfolio__c-Model page not using the global action it works fine also. When I look at the list of global actions I can see it is installed and I'm able to drag the global action onto the page layout to use.

Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003eibQAA) for this.

I am wondering if this also fails for dev/sandbox orgs.

Comment: Note I see the same issues when installing into a dev org (no namespace)